# How can i fix "Error 0:60 samplers cannot be structure or block members" in OpenGL?

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, fragment-shader

When running the code, I get the error "samplers cannot be structure or block members".

I found out it's because my hardware doesn't allow this lines:

```
struct Material
{
    sampler2D diffuse;
    sampler2D specular;
    float shininess;
};
```

My immediate solution was to declare both sampler2D objects as "uniform"

```
uniform sampler2D Mdiffuse;
uniform sampler2D Mspecular;
```

And then change every line where the objects are used, to their new names (instead of material.diffuse and material.specular). Although this did remove the error, the objects are still not being drawn.

Here's the full fragment shader if it's necessary (original, without my changes).

```
#version 330 core

#define NUMBER_OF_POINT_LIGHTS 4

struct Material
{
    sampler2D diffuse;
    sampler2D specular;
    float shininess;
};

struct DirLight
{
    vec3 direction;
    
    vec3 ambient;
    vec3 diffuse;
    vec3 specular;
};

struct PointLight
{
    vec3 position;
    
    float constant;
    float linear;
    float quadratic;
    
    vec3 ambient;
    vec3 diffuse;
    vec3 specular;
};

struct SpotLight
{
    vec3 position;
    vec3 direction;
    float cutOff;
    float outerCutOff;
    
    float constant;
    float linear;
    float quadratic;
    
    vec3 ambient;
    vec3 diffuse;
    vec3 specular;
};

in vec3 FragPos;
in vec3 Normal;
in vec2 TexCoords;

out vec4 color;

uniform vec3 viewPos;
uniform DirLight dirLight;
uniform PointLight pointLights[NUMBER_OF_POINT_LIGHTS];
uniform SpotLight spotLight;
uniform Material material;




// Function prototypes
vec3 CalcDirLight( DirLight light, vec3 normal, vec3 viewDir );
vec3 CalcPointLight( PointLight light, vec3 normal, vec3 fragPos, vec3 viewDir );
vec3 CalcSpotLight( SpotLight light, vec3 normal, vec3 fragPos, vec3 viewDir );

void main( )
{
    // Properties
    vec3 norm = normalize( Normal );
    vec3 viewDir = normalize( viewPos - FragPos );
    
    // Directional lighting
    vec3 result = CalcDirLight( dirLight, norm, viewDir );
    
    // Point lights
    for ( int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_POINT_LIGHTS; i++ )
    {
        result += CalcPointLight( pointLights[i], norm, FragPos, viewDir );
    }
    
    // Spot light
    result += CalcSpotLight( spotLight, norm, FragPos, viewDir );
    
    
    /*color = vec4( result,texture( material.diffuse, TexCoords).a );
      if(color.a < 0.1)
        discard;*/
}

// Calculates the color when using a directional light.
vec3 CalcDirLight( DirLight light, vec3 normal, vec3 viewDir )
{
    vec3 lightDir = normalize( -light.direction );
    
    // Diffuse shading
    float diff = max( dot( normal, lightDir ), 0.0 );
    
    // Specular shading
    vec3 reflectDir = reflect( -lightDir, normal );
    float spec = pow( max( dot( viewDir, reflectDir ), 0.0 ), material.shininess );
    
    // Combine results
    vec3 ambient = light.ambient * vec3( texture( material.diffuse, TexCoords ).rgb );
    vec3 diffuse = light.diffuse * diff * vec3( texture( material.diffuse, TexCoords ).rgb );
    vec3 specular = light.specular * spec * vec3( texture( material.specular, TexCoords ).rgb );

    
    /*vec4 result= vec4(ambient + diffuse + specular,texture( material.diffuse, TexCoords).a) ;
      if(result.a < 0.1)
        discard;*/
            vec3 result=ambient + diffuse + specular;

    return (result);
}

// Calculates the color when using a point light.
vec3 CalcPointLight( PointLight light, vec3 normal, vec3 fragPos, vec3 viewDir )
{
    vec3 lightDir = normalize( light.position - fragPos );
    
    // Diffuse shading
    float diff = max( dot( normal, lightDir ), 0.0 );
    
    // Specular shading
    vec3 reflectDir = reflect( -lightDir, normal );
    float spec = pow( max( dot( viewDir, reflectDir ), 0.0 ), material.shininess );
    
    // Attenuation
    float distance = length( light.position - fragPos );
    float attenuation = 1.0f / ( light.constant + light.linear * distance + light.quadratic * ( distance * distance ) );
    
    // Combine results
    vec3 ambient = light.ambient * vec3( texture( material.diffuse, TexCoords ).rgb );
    vec3 diffuse = light.diffuse * diff * vec3( texture( material.diffuse, TexCoords ).rgb );
    vec3 specular = light.specular * spec * vec3( texture( material.specular, TexCoords ).rgb );

    
    ambient *= attenuation;
    diffuse *= attenuation;
    specular *= attenuation;

  /* vec4 result= vec4(ambient + diffuse + specular,texture( material.diffuse, TexCoords).a) ;
      if(result.a < 0.1)
        discard;*/
        vec3 result=ambient + diffuse + specular;

    return (result);
    
}

// Calculates the color when using a spot light.
vec3 CalcSpotLight( SpotLight light, vec3 normal, vec3 fragPos, vec3 viewDir )
{
    vec3 lightDir = normalize( light.position - fragPos );
    
    // Diffuse shading
    float diff = max( dot( normal, lightDir ), 0.0 );
    
    // Specular shading
    vec3 reflectDir = reflect( -lightDir, normal );
    float spec = pow( max( dot( viewDir, reflectDir ), 0.0 ), material.shininess );
    
    // Attenuation
    float distance = length( light.position - fragPos );
    float attenuation = 1.0f / ( light.constant + light.linear * distance + light.quadratic * ( distance * distance ) );
    
    // Spotlight intensity
    float theta = dot( lightDir, normalize( -light.direction ) );
    float epsilon = light.cutOff - light.outerCutOff;
    float intensity = clamp( ( theta - light.outerCutOff ) / epsilon, 0.0, 1.0 );
    
    // Combine results
    vec3 ambient = light.ambient * vec3( texture( material.diffuse, TexCoords ).rgb );
    vec3 diffuse = light.diffuse * diff * vec3( texture( material.diffuse, TexCoords ).rgb );
    vec3 specular = light.specular * spec * vec3( texture( material.specular, TexCoords ).rgb );

    
    ambient *= attenuation * intensity;
    diffuse *= attenuation * intensity;
    specular *= attenuation * intensity;

    /*  vec4 result= vec4(ambient + diffuse + specular,texture( material.diffuse, TexCoords).a) ;
      if(result.a < 0.1)
        discard;*/

        vec3 result=ambient + diffuse + specular;

    return (result);
    
}
```

Comment: it says that samplers can't be inside blocks. So don't put samplers inside blocks. And your shader doesn't set the colour so how does it know what to draw?

Comment: @user253751 Read the complete question.

Comment: @Rabbid76 The second part of the question is "objects are not being drawn, why?"

Comment: @user253751 Sorry but your comment doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 0):

Check that if you replace usages of texture(Mdiffuse/MSpecular) with hardcoded colors that something actually shows up. If so, check that you are loading and binding the textures properly before your draw calls.